# vue v-for loop, add class individual

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using v-for to loop through a list and display that list.

Now after rendering, each list has a title and hidden content, and I want to be able, once I select one title of that list, to have its content to be shown and not all content.

So far I am doing this (thanks to [@thanksd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2678454/thanksd)):

```
<div class="link">
  <p @click="show = true"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="link">
  <p @click="show = true"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>

data() {
  return {
    show: false,
  };
}
```

Comment: I'd create a component for each list item

Comment: @Peter what do you think that you are doing by down voting my posts just for english grammar mistakes ? English is not my primary language, and my family didn't have money to send me to fancy English Courses but I learned everything I know from Movies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
<div class="link" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <p @click="show = index"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show === index" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you are iterating an object, the syntax is `v-for="(value, key) in items"`. Also it's a recommended practice now to declare `key` in loops.

Read relevant doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for).

Comment: thank you very much, following your advice, now I will be using key in each loop since I was not doing it :) Thank you! 
PS. This worked perfect by the way! Thnx

Comment: @Marketingexpert Actually, if you upgrade to the latest version of Vue, you will see warnings in console if you doesn't declare `key`. This is not mandatory now but could potentially improve performance. Here's the [doc](http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key).

Comment: I am using "vue": "^2.2.4", and I didn't receive any error, even though I will be using since it's recommended :) thnx for bringing it to my attentions

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, if you are building the variable that will list the content, then it's easier

```
<div class="link" v-for="link in links">
  <p @click="link.show = true"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="link.show" class="content">
    <p>{{ link.content }}</p>
  </div>
</div>

data() {
  return {
    links: [{
        title: 'the title',
        content: 'the hidden content',
        show: false,
    },{
        title: 'the other title',
        content: 'the other hidden content',
        show: false,
    },]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to hide it when the user click on it by second time you need to add a ternary comparation "show === index ? show = -1 : show = index" to the @Leo answer:

```
<div class="link" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
  <p @click="show === index ? show = -1 : show = index"> Click here to show the content </p>
  <div v-show="show === index" class="content">
    <p>This is the hidden content</p>
  </div>
</div>

data() {
  return {
    show: -1,
  };
}
```